# Error syncing data from Collector app?

Tags: arcgis-collector

I am getting the

> Unable to synchronize replica, sync replica internal

error in the collector app. We have interns out in the field and this just started happening after the second week, so I am confused. We can't just reload the map because then we could lose 50 data points that they have collected throughout our county.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Did you change the schema at all after people went out in the field? I have no idea why they chose to go this route, but the Collector can't handle this use case...

Comment: It is possible to recover data from a device that cant sync: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012460 You can then add the data manually by editing. To solve the sync problems i would start by reinstalling the collector app.